# Showing an image through path stored in MySQL

Tags: php, html

I would like the image to be displayed inside a table. At the moment I am getting this message when I exectue the file: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING 
If someone could point me in the right direction I'de really appreciate it.

```
<tr><td>
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db ("...");
$query = ("select * from photos where ID = 3");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." ".$query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<p>$row[title]</p></ br></ br>";
echo "<img src=' . $row['content'] . ' height='200' width='200'/>"; 
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
</td></tr>
```

Comment: Where is the path? you probably have only the image filename stored, and not the full path. So do a concatenation of the full path and not $row['content']

Comment: what problem are you facing with this?

Comment: I get the error message mentioned above

Comment: No I am sure the whole path address is stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is on this line, because you're mixing single and double quotes:

`echo "<img src=' . $row['content'] . ' height='200' width='200'/>";`

You could rewrite it like this: `echo "<img src='$row[content]' height='200' width='200'/>";`

Or like this:
`echo "<img src='" . $row[content] . "' height='200' width='200'/>";`

Answer (score 0):

are you storing your images in the DB as BLOB type, or on the file system and referencing the location of the pic file from the DB?

assuming you are showing local file path to pic it might be like this:

```
<tr><td>
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db ("...");
$query = ("select * from photos where ID = 3");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." ".$query);

$path = "path/to/the/pic/";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<p>$row[title]</p></ br></ br>";
echo "<img src='".$path.$row['content']."' height='200' width='200'/>"; 
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
</td></tr>
```

difficult to really know what you are after from your question though, can you show us the DB structure....

Comment: the adress for the image is stored in the "content" field of the "photos" table. I want to echo this image on a web page through the address stored in "content".

Comment: note use of " and ' in the echo line: 
echo "<img src='".$path.$row['content']."' height='200' width='200'/>";

assuming the full path is in the DB:

echo "<img src='".$row['content']."' height='200' width='200'/>";

Comment: note you are creating array elements, best off to pull it out of the quoted echo like this. have you thought about using mysql_fetch_object(), would then look like this:
echo "<img src='.$row->content."' height='200' width='200'/>";

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<img src=\"path/to/the/image/" . $row['content'] . "\" height=\"200\" width=\"200\"/>";
```